# Android/XML - How to align an immobile layout to top of parent and have scrollview below?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-scrollview

Please refer to example below. I want to have the top layout (below encased in red) to be unmoving in a scrollview in my activity. I have a scrollview as the parent layout and then I thought having a relative layout for the top one would work, and align it to the top, but that didn't really work out as it still remained within the scrollview. I would like to have the users have the red-layout box remain static when they scroll down.

I figure I would also have to put in a topMargin at the top of the scrollview or something in order to fit the redbox layout in.

[image]

**XML Code posted here**: http://pastebin.com/bxdREbeG

Comment: don't make ScrollView as root, but Vertical LinearLayout{Immobile,ScrollView}

Comment: also I suggest to you to use ListView instead of that insane xml with scrollview hardcoded items

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this (hand code, for reference only):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/YourTopStaticView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"> //Or any other height you want

        //Contents of the top view

    </RelativeLyout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/YourTopStaticView">

        //Contents of the ScrollView

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As a side note, do not hardcode children into the `ScrollView` like that. Use the `RecyclerView` (which is an updated, modern replacement for `ListView`), which you will be expected to know how to use if you want to move into serious Android programming. It is actually super easy to use, once you get the hang of it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ScrollView with only one child (official documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). According to your xml, your ScrollView is very complicated with a lot of child widgets.

The best option for you is to use a LinearLayout as the root for the whole container, a LinearLayout( or Relative) for the top layout containing the Reset and Save buttons, and a ListView for the long list that you have. ListView takes care of it's own scrolling. So you don't have to worry about that.

This will improve your code performance as well.

Comment: The scrollview does have only one child. That is a single layout. That layout however, has more layouts and children under them that end in a button and edittext. I'll look into listview then.

Answer (score 0):

This should suit your needs:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Multi TTS Implementation"/>


        <Button android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="SAVE"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/resetAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/save"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="RESET ALL"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView android:id="@id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/topPanel"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <!-- Your scrollable content here -->

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```